# Kohana validation 'matches' rule

Tags: validation, kohana

I am using **Kohana 3.3** for a project where have a model class which extends the ORM. There is a corresponding table to this model in the MySQL database. In this table, there are a 3 columns which should not have the same values. I have also a view where the user can add to this model, where item1,2,3 are text input fields. 
I am trying to write the validation in the model which enforces the rule that item1,2,3 cannot have the same values. 
The structure and relevant part of code is something like this:

**Database table:**

```
id | column1 | othercolumns | item1 | item2 | item3
```

**Model class:**

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        "item1" => array( array('matches', array(':validation',':field','item2') ) ),
        "item1" => array( array('matches', array(':validation',':field','item3') ) ),
        //same for item2 and item3
    );
}
```

I read [this](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/examples/validation), [this](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Validate#matches) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143681/how-to-apply-the-matches-validation-rule-in-kohana-3-1) page, and I am not able to understand how to correctly implement this **directly in the model**.
(I could do this in JavaScript on the client side, but I want to avoid doing that leave it to the framework!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a validation callback:

```
return array(
    'item1' => array(function($field, Validation $object, $compare1, $compare2) {
        $values = array($object[$field], $object[$compare1], $object[$compare2]);
        if (count(array_unique($values)) < count($values))
        {
            $object->error($field, 'unique_fields');
        }
    }, array(':field', ':validation', 'item2', 'item3'))
);
```

Its just a quick example. For example, you can use dynamic field count.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what's happening here now! Appreciate the help!